# Efficient short SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I Have This Table called papers

```
|ID | Paper_Code | Subject_Code |
| 0 | 2018/Eng/01|     ENG      |
| 1 | 2018/Eng/02|     ENG      |
| 2 | 2018/CS/01 |     CS       |
| 3 | 2018/Sci/01|     Sci      |
| 4 | 2018/Eng/03|     ENG      |
```

I Want The Results to be

```
|ID | Paper_Code | Subject_Code |
| 4 | 2018/Eng/03|     ENG      |
| 2 | 2018/CS/01 |     CS       |
| 3 | 2018/Sci/01|     Sci      |
```

I Have tried

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(Paper_Code) 
     FROM papers WHERE Subject_Code = (SELECT DISTINCT Subject_Code))";
```

I'm new to sql, tried alot of times but kept failing.

Comment: Please see below

Comment: You don't need to post a comment when you add an answer, the poster is notified automatically.

Comment: You should explain the logic that you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.* from yourtable a join (
select subject_code, max(id)id
from yourtable
group by subject_code) b 
on a.subject_code=b.subject_code and a.id=b.id
```

Comment: He wants `MAX(paper_code)`, not `MAX(id)`

Comment: Above code will get him the data set he wants

Comment: I think it's just a coincidence that it gives the same answer.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think op know what he want.

Comment: His attempted query uses `MAX(paper_code)`. I think that makes it obvious what he's trying to maximize for each subject code.

Comment: @ Daniel Marcus Thanks loads You're a Champ i really struggled with this Thanks Mate

Comment: Great! Please upvote/accept answer

Comment: i wanted to get rows with the max(paper_code) for Distinct Subject_code

Comment: @ Daniel Marcus i tried up voting it, it says that its recorded but since my reputation is below 15 it won't be shown publicly

Comment: OK you can also click the check mark as well